# Django timezone.now()'s value is not changing

Tags: django

I'm trying to annotate a queryset with a certain value. This is my annotation:

```
def annotate_time(self, name='time'):
        annotation = {
            name: Case(
                When(
                    datetime_submitted__isnull=False,
                    then=((F('datetime_submitted') - F('datetime_started')) / 1000000)
                ),
                When(
                    task__end_time__lt=timezone.now(),
                    then=((F('task__end_time') - F('datetime_started')) / 1000000)
                ),
                default=((timezone.now() - F('datetime_started'))),
                output_field=IntegerField()
            )
        }

        return self.annotate(**annotation)
```

The first two `When` cases are already working, but I'm not sure why, if the `default` case is the selected case, **the values are always constant** for all of the items in the queryset no matter how many times this function runs.
Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

The default is probably being instantiated at compile time, so you might be able to get past this by setting it at the beginning of the function, i.e:

```
def annotate_time(self, name='time'):
    d = timezone.now() - F('datetime_started')
    annotation = {
        name: Case(
            When(
                datetime_submitted__isnull=False,
                then=((F('datetime_submitted') - F('datetime_started')) / 1000000)
            ),
            When(
                task__end_time__lt=timezone.now(),
                then=((F('task__end_time') - F('datetime_started')) / 1000000)
            ),
            default=d,
            output_field=IntegerField()
        )
    }

    return self.annotate(**annotation)
```

It may be worth noting that the default value is supposed to be a constant, so another way around this would be doing another `When` statement to cover the remaining cases

Comment: Looking at the source code for the `Case` function it looks like I'm right, the default is evaluated in the `__init__`, so my solution should work

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry, both of your suggestions didn't work. I tried doing the first one by moving the value of the `default` outside, but it didn't work. I then proceed to creating a completely new `When` for it, still didn't work. The same constant times

Answer (score 0):

After a series of trial and error, I finally was able to make it work. Instead of just using `timezone.now()` directly, I formatted it and used `timezone.now().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')`.